# How to Get Current Custom Post Type Selected Taxonomy Term (Not All Terms)

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, custom-taxonomy, theme-development

I need to get ONLY the term (not all terms) of Current Custom Post Type. For example I have a Custom Post type called movies and have a Taxonomy called Genre which has some terms like comedy, action,... now in current post I need to get the used term?

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'movies', 'posts_per_page' => 10 );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
  the_title();
  echo '<div class="entry-content">';
  the_content();
  echo '</div>';
endwhile;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve this.

**Using [get_the_terms](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/)**:

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'movies', 'posts_per_page' => 10 );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
    <?php
    the_title();

    $terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'genre' );
    if ( is_array( $terms ) ) {
        //Manipulate array of WP_Term objects
    }
    ?>
    <div class="entry-content">
    <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

**using [get_the_term_list:](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_term_list/)**

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'movies', 'posts_per_page' => 10 );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
    <?php
    the_title();

    echo get_the_term_list( get_the_ID(), 'genre' );
    ?>
    <div class="entry-content">
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```